# Android MultiAutocompleteTextView Unicode input support

Tags: android, unicode, multiautocompletetextview

I have implemented a MultiAutocompleteTextView to get user input but it cannot handle Hindi input the way an edit text can. When I pick data from my edit text I get the Unicode text in my database but it doesn't seem to work in the MultiAutocomplete TextView and it gets converted to gibberish!

Is there any way to get Unicode data from the MultiAutocompleteTextView. It only seems to support UTF-8 as of now. Or is there a workaround for this.

I wish to have users get auto-suggestion while they type in their native language.

Comment: How can I improve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to handle this. I resorted to using a simple Edit Text instead.